# No sound on 14.04 - various troubleshooting tried already

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, vlc

I've not used my laptop in about a week, I came back to it to stream some media from my NAS. Installed VLC and a couple of plugins since the file I was trying to play (mkv) was not working.

I'm now getting no sound whatsoever from media such as YouTube, Spotify or media from my NAS. I do, however, get the initial login sound when the laptop is started up and the test sound plays in sound settings.

I've looked at a few threads that suggest alsa messing up and I've tried the troubleshooting in them with no results. I've even went as far as uninstalling pulseaudio and alsa then reinstalling.

I've also tried editing the speech-dispatcher file in /etc/default but this was correct so did not need edited. I'm at a bit of a loss for what else to try, I've read a few threads but most seem to have the same troubleshooting steps that have not worked.

EDIT: I've plugged the laptop into a TV with a HDMI cable. The sound plays through the TV, so it sounds like the sound is being redirected wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you have (you said you've tried Pulse Audio) but did you access it through `pavucontrol`?

Have you tried

`amixer set Master 100`

I have had some sound issues in Ubuntu 14.04 (now I'm using 16.04, but none yet...) which started after plugging in my headphones. I thought it had to do with the jack, but these steps fixed it for me.

I think at that time, the main volume in `pavucontrol` was muted.